# Ruby: Hash: use one record attribute as key and another as value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a `User` with attributes `name` and `badge_number`

For a JavaScript autocomplete field I want the user to be able to start typing the user's name and get a select list.

I'm using [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) which offers the JS needed, I just need to provide it the data in this format:

```
data: { "Sarah Person": 13241, "Billiam Gregory": 54665, "Stephan Stevenston": 98332 }
```

This won't do:

```
User.select(:name, :badge_number) => { name: "Sarah Person", badge_number: 13241, ... }
```

And this feels repetitive, icky and redundant (and repetitive):

```
user_list = User.select(:name, :badge_number)
hsh = {}
user_list.each do |user|
  hsh[user.name] = user.badge_number
end
hsh
```

...though it does give me my intended result, performance will suck over time.

Any better ways than this weird, slimy loop?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that loop. Are you using ActiveRecord?

Comment: Yep, ActiveRecord. As I add more users, this loop will take longer. And since I'll be ajax-ing it, I wanna keep it pretty fast.

Comment: At the end of the day, no matter how you write it, something—be it your code or a library function—is going to have to loop through the records in the resultset to build the hash. There's simply no way around it.

Comment: Fair point. I just prefer to keep loops out of my code if possible (and it is with `:pluck`)

Comment: @Chiperific That's not really how software works. You can't make anything faster just by avoiding loops, they're a fundamentally important part of software development, and code that uses loops isn't inherently slow. In this case, `pluck` and your loop will perform more or less identically, you're just hiding the complexity in Rails.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give the desired output

`User.pluck(:name, :badge_number).to_h`

**Edit**

Though above code is one liner, it still have loop internally. Offloading such loops to database may improve the performance when dealing with too many rows. But there is no database agnostic way to achieve this in active record. Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51251832/1116381) for achieving this in Postgres

Answer (score 1):

If your RDBMS is Postgresql, you can use Postgresql function [`json_build_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) for this specific case.

```
User.select("json_build_object(name, badge_number) as json_col")
    .map(&:json_col)
```

The whole json can be build using Postgresql supplied functions too.

```
User.select("array_to_json(array_agg(json_build_object(name, badge_number))) as json_col")
    .limit(1)[0]
    .json_col
```